# Insert text into python tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, char

I have been making a program that responds to a user input. When I run it my code doesn't insert the response into the text widget. I get the error:

> TypeError: insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'chars'

My code is:

```
global stuff
stuff = open("Dictionary.txt", "r")
global contents
contents = stuff.read()
stuff.close()
from tkinter import *

dictionary = {"chungus": "Come at me chungus ... you wanna go?",
                      "hi": "It's good to see you!", "bot": "No - you're the BOT"}

def output():
    TT = entry.get()
    text.delete(0.0, END)
    try:
        meaning = dictionary[TT]
    except:
        meaning = "We do not have a reply for this yet..."
    text.insert(meaning)

def words():
    TT = (contents)
    text.delete(0.0, END)
    meaning = (TT)
    text.insert(END, meaning)




global window
window = Tk()
window.title("WFR")
label1 = Label(window, text="Enter stuff for reply (No caps):    ")
label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
entry = Entry(window, width=35, bg="light green")
entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
button1 = Button(window, text="SUBMIT", width=8, command=output)
button1.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
text = Text(window, width=60, height=20, wrap=WORD, background="yellow")
text.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
menubar = Menu(window)
firstmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
firstmenu.add_command(label="Type What?", command=words)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Options", menu=firstmenu)
window.config(menu=menubar)
window.mainloop()
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: Commenting out the three stuff statements (2,4 and 5) and adding the `END` to the `text.insert(END, meaning)` at 19 - per PNX's answer below will work. Entering values from the dict respond correctly and get the no reply message when an error.

Comment: Please share the **entire** error message. Don’t use `import *`, it’s rarely a good idea.

Comment: Read the advice in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  It is great for debugging as well as asking better questions if you fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something quite simple to answer. In your code you have written `text.insert(END, meaning)`, earlier in a different area you have typed `text.insert(meaning)`. I think this is simply you missing something as you type your code. Try to copy the correct version of code (with the END, before it) in the line where you are getting your issue. Also, may I suggest adding comments to your code as it makes it a lot easier to see where the issue is.